# JavaScript client side validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have designed a login page, but client side validation is not working. I have written JavaScript code for validation. And how to make email extension acceptance only particular comp id. ex: user@example.com. It should accept only example.com email id's. I have tried to to give extension: "example.com" in JavaScript validation, but it's not working.

Code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Font CSS (Via CDN) -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700'>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!--Table container---->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/ValidationFormScript.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <!-- Navbar content -->
  </nav>
  <!---Body starts here---->
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <section class="login-block">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 banner-sec">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 login-sec">
          <!---Break line after header ---->
          <br />
          <!--- Form starts here----->
          <form class="login-form" method="" action="" id="admin-form">
            <!---- Starts the User ID section--->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail" class="text-left"><span>User ID</span></label>
              <span class="input-status" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="Input your email"></span>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email">
            </div>
            <!---- Starts the Password section--->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword" class="text-left"><span>Password</span></label>
              <span class="input-status" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="Input your password"></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="enter password">
            </div>
            <!---- Ends the Password section--->
            <!---Submit button--->
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-right">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!----- Script for Validation----->
    <!-- jQuery Validate Plugin-->
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      
        "use strict";
      
        // Init Theme Core    
        Core.init();
      
        // Init Demo JS     
        Demo.init();
      
        /* @custom validation method (smartCaptcha) 
        ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
      
        $.validator.methods.smartCaptcha = function(value, element, param) {
          return value == param;
        };
      
        $("#admin-form").validate({
      
          /* @validation states + elements 
          ------------------------------------------- */
      
          errorClass: "state-error",
          validClass: "state-success",
          errorElement: "em",
      
          /* @validation rules 
          ------------------------------------------ */
      
          rules: {
            firstname: {
              required: true
            },
            lastname: {
              required: true
            },
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true,
        extension: ""
            },
            website: {
              required: true,
              url: true
            },
            language: {
              required: true
            },
            upload1: {
              required: true,
              extension: "jpg|png|gif|jpeg|doc|docx|pdf|xls|rar|zip"
            },
            mobileos: {
              required: true
            },
            comment: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 30
            },
            mobile_phone: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
            },
            home_phone: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
            },
            password: {
              required: true,
                      },
            repeatPassword: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 6,
              maxlength: 16,
              equalTo: '#password'
            },
            gender: {
              required: true
            },
            languages: {
              required: true
            },
            verification: {
              required: true,
              smartCaptcha: 19
            },
            applicant_age: {
              required: true,
              min: 16
            },
            licence_no: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("#applicant_age").val() > 19;
              }
            },
            child_name: {
              required: "#parents:checked"
            }
      
          },
      
          /* @validation error messages 
          ---------------------------------------------- */
      
          messages: {
            firstname: {
              required: 'Enter first name'
            },
            lastname: {
              required: 'Enter last name'
            },
            useremail: {
              required: 'Enter email address',
              email: 'Enter a VALID email address'
            },
            website: {
              required: 'Enter your website URL',
              url: 'URL should start with - http://www'
            },
            language: {
              required: 'Choose a language'
            },
            upload1: {
              required: 'Please browse a file',
              extension: 'File format not supported'
            },
            mobileos: {
              required: 'Please select a mobile platform'
            },
            comment: {
              required: 'Oops you forgot to comment',
              minlength: 'Enter at least 30 characters or more'
            },
            mobile_phone: {
              require_from_group: 'Fill at least a mobile contact'
            },
            home_phone: {
              require_from_group: 'Fill at least a home contact'
            },
            password: {
              required: 'Please enter a password'
            },
            repeatPassword: {
              required: 'Please repeat the above password',
              equalTo: 'Password mismatch detected'
            },
            gender: {
              required: 'Please choose specie'
            },
            languages: {
              required: 'Select laguages spoken'
            },
            verification: {
              required: 'Please enter verification code',
              smartCaptcha: 'Oops - enter a correct verification code'
            },
            applicant_age: {
              required: 'Enter applicant age',
              min: 'Must be 16 years and above'
            },
            licence_no: {
              required: 'Enter licence number'
            },
            child_name: {
              required: 'Please enter your childs name'
            }
      
          },
      
          /* @validation highlighting + error placement  
          ---------------------------------------------------- */
      
          highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.field').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
          },
          unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.field').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
          },
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")) {
              element.closest('.option-group').after(error);
            } else {
              error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
          }
      
        });
      
      
        // Cache several DOM elements
        var pageHeader = $('.content-header').find('b');
        var adminForm = $('.admin-form');
        var options = adminForm.find('.option');
        var switches = adminForm.find('.switch');
        var buttons = adminForm.find('.button');
        var Panel = adminForm.find('.panel');
      
        // Form Skin Switcher
        $('#skin-switcher a').on('click', function() {
          var btnData = $(this).data('form-skin');
      
          $('#skin-switcher a').removeClass('item-active');
          $(this).addClass('item-active')
      
          adminForm.each(function(i, e) {
            var skins = 'theme-primary theme-info theme-success theme-warning theme-danger theme-alert theme-system theme-dark'
            var panelSkins = 'panel-primary panel-info panel-success panel-warning panel-danger panel-alert panel-system panel-dark'
            $(e).removeClass(skins).addClass('theme-' + btnData);
            Panel.removeClass(panelSkins).addClass('panel-' + btnData);
            pageHeader.removeClass().addClass('text-' + btnData);
          });
      
          $(options).each(function(i, e) {
            if ($(e).hasClass('block')) {
              $(e).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 option option-' + btnData);
            } else {
              $(e).removeClass().addClass('option option-' + btnData);
            }
          });
      
          // var sliders = $('.ui-timepicker-div', adminForm).find('.ui-slider');
          $('body').find('.ui-slider').each(function(i, e) {
            $(e).addClass('slider-primary');
          });
      
          $(switches).each(function(i, ele) {
            if ($(ele).hasClass('switch-round')) {
              if ($(ele).hasClass('block')) {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 switch switch-round switch-' + btnData);
              } else {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('switch switch-round switch-' + btnData);
              }
            } else {
              if ($(ele).hasClass('block')) {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 switch switch-' + btnData);
              } else {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('switch switch-' + btnData);
              }
            }
      
          });
          buttons.removeClass().addClass('button btn-' + btnData);
        });
      
        setTimeout(function() {
          adminForm.addClass('theme-primary');
          Panel.addClass('panel-primary');
          pageHeader.addClass('text-primary');
      
          $(options).each(function(i, e) {
            if ($(e).hasClass('block')) {
              $(e).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 option option-primary');
            } else {
              $(e).removeClass().addClass('option option-primary');
            }
          });
      
          // var sliders = $('.ui-timepicker-div', adminForm).find('.ui-slider');
          $('body').find('.ui-slider').each(function(i, e) {
            $(e).addClass('slider-primary');
          });
      
          $(switches).each(function(i, ele) {
            if ($(ele).hasClass('switch-round')) {
              if ($(ele).hasClass('block')) {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 switch switch-round switch-primary');
              } else {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('switch switch-round switch-primary');
              }
            } else {
              if ($(ele).hasClass('block')) {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('block mt15 switch switch-primary');
              } else {
                $(ele).removeClass().addClass('switch switch-primary');
              }
            }
          });
          buttons.removeClass().addClass('button btn-primary');
        }, 800);
      
      
      
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
        @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css");
.login-block{
    background: #fff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
float:left;
width:100%;
padding : 50px 0;
}
.banner-sec{background:#fff;  no-repeat left bottom; background-size:cover; min-height:0px; border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; padding:0;}

.carousel-inner{border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
}
.login-sec{padding: 60px 30px; position:relative;}
.login-sec .copy-text{position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:20px; font-size:13px; text-align:left;}
.login-sec .copy-text i{color:#FEB58A;}
.login-sec .copy-text a{color:#E36262;}
.login-sec h2{margin-bottom:30px; font-weight:400; font-size:30px; color: grey;}
.btn-login{background: #90EE90; color:#000; font-weight:400;}
.banner-text{width:70%; position:absolute; bottom:40px; padding-left:20px;}
.banner-text p{color:#fff;}
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    right: 26%;
    bottom: 160px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font: Century Gothic;
 font-weight: 400;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Century Gothic,Century Gothic,Century Gothic;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: grey;
    background-color: #fff;
}
 .palel-primary
 {
  border-color: #bce8f1;
 }
 .panel-primary>.panel-heading
 {
  background:#bce8f1;
  
 }
 .panel-primary>.panel-body
 {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
 }
 
 input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block; 
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left:20px
}

label {
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 80px;
}
 .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 77%;
    height: 32px;
 }
 .label{
 color: black;
 }
 label span { color: black; 
 font-weight: normal !important;}
 
 a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
body {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
    </style>
```

JavaScript code for validation, but it's not working.

Comment: your snippet is not working. Please upload a  working snippet.

Comment: please share what is written in ValidationFormScript.js, this might overwriting default validation rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an attribute called, 'pattern' (*based on regular expressions*). It should look like,

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+"/>
```

Optionally, you can also publish custom error messages using  event handler attributes like oninput, onvalid,... It brings value and helpful to direct the users with more precise & meaningful messages.

Comment: Exactly. But i need to display, if email is wrong enter the correct email address. Here problem is when i click on the submit button its not displaying anything.

Comment: By just modifying my statement in your code, I was able to display that standard error message, 'Please match the request format'. This error message is generic if you entered an email address that does not follow the regex pattern, [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can get custom error messages when overriding event handler attributes like oninput, onvalid,...

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to use the email input to validate, it is better to use javascript to validate the input and show error messages.

```js
function checkRegistration() {
    var email = document.getElementById('login-email').value;
    var alertMessage = document.getElementById('alert-email');
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    var isValid = re.test(email);
    if (isValid) {
      alertMessage.innerHTML = '';
      alertMessage.style.opacity = 0;
      alertMessage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }  else { 
      alertMessage.innerHTML = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
      alertMessage.style.opacity = 1;
      alertMessage.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

```css
#alert-email {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear,opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkRegistration()">
  <div>
    <label>User ID</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="enter email" id="login-email" />
  </div>
  <span id="alert-email"></span>
  <div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password"  placeholder="enter password" id="login-password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-right">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new require for JQuery validate:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("email_domain", function (value, element) {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(domain|domain2)\.com$/;
    if(!regex.test(value)) {
       return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
 });
```

Then add "email_domain" to form require validate